# Reduce records count in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with: **id**, **pointId**, **pointValue** with about 10.000.000 rows.

I have to to reduce it by deleting 90% rows, so I need to leave every tenth record, and delete any other.

Using **id** from table isn't good idea because this is not sequence of consecutive numbers.

How can I do it by query?

Comment: So just delete random records?

Comment: If you need 'random' values, it doesn't matter if you will have there more or less records, I think you can delete all rows where `MOD(id,10) != 0`. Sure, it can returns 985.000 or 1.003.000 records, does it matter?

Comment: @panther but i can't use **id**, better will be use row number but how to do it?

Comment: Every tenth value based on what?  You don't explain what you want to accomplish well enough, is the problem that id isn't consecutive and that you'd want to delete every 10'th one sorted by id?  If id is some kind of random value or a GUID, you could just delete the top million.  Per your comment, row number by what?  Unless you sort by some value it is nonsensical.

Comment: so where do you get this "row number" from?

Comment: And are you really expecting to delete from a set of 10 Million records?

Comment: @ELP24: why you can't use id (or better, modulo for id)? It deletes approx. 90% of records, it's the target you need to achieve. Maybe it'll be 91%, maybe 89%, does it matter?

Comment: Sorry for my unclear description. I missed addtional column "datetime" it's timestamp. So table is sorted by datetime. Id is not sequence of consecutive numbers, it looks like: 978,986,992,999,1021.....
So maybe there is a some solution to get rownumber ordered by datetime and delete something like MOD(rownumber,10) != 0

Comment: And that's why they made an EDIT button. Also, why do you have to reduce the number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you really need to delete so many millions of records.
But, following approach may help you.

You can generate dynamic `'row_number'` based on which you can filter every `10th` row and delete *rest of* the records.

**Example**:

Assuming that the table name is `'points_table'`.

```
delete from points_table
 where id NOT IN (
    select id from (
     select @rn:=@rn+1 as row_num, p.id
      from points_table p, (select @rn:=0) rn
    ) list_of_ids_to_be_deleted
    where row_num % 10 = 0
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:-

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE ID NOT IN
(SELECT ID FROM (SELECT @RN:=@RN+1, ID, POINTID, POINTVAL
                 FROM TABLE_NAME, (SELECT @RN:=0) T) T1
                 WHERE MOD(@RN,10) = 0)
```

This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that should delete 90% of your rows assuming you've got 10 million rows.

```
  DELETE FROM MyTable  WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM MyTable LIMIT 9000000);
```